# PDO namespace not found, while doing it correctly

Tags: php, pdo

So namespacing and PDO, with the experience that I'm having now, I see it as hell.

```
Warning: include_once(C:/xampp2/htdocs\application\classes\class.pdo.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp2\htdocs\application\bootstrap.php on line 18

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'C:/xampp2/htdocs\application\classes\class.pdo.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp2\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp2\htdocs\application\bootstrap.php on line 18

Fatal error: Class 'C_Red\Storage\PDO' not found in C:\xampp2\htdocs\application\classes\class.database.php on line 13
```

How is this happening if I'm connecting like this:

```
public static function init()
    {
        global $_CONFIG;
        try
        {
            self::$conn = new \PDO('mysql:hostname=127.0.0.1;dbname=c_red,root,123',array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
        }
            catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            throw new PDOException ($e->getMessage);
        }
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
    }
```

Is it not the job of the `\` in front of PDO to set that it's not in the namespace that I'm working in?

How is this error possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd start by checking the use of backslashes/forward slashes on your include declaration. I'm betting that the $_CONFIG['database']['hostname'] isn't accommodating which slashes should be used for the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't merely the `new \PDO()` constructor which must be namespaced, but also references to its constants and exceptions.  You declare PDO attributes later in the constructor, but don't namespace them with a backslash:

```
// First fix the namespacing...
self::$conn = new \PDO('mysql:hostname=127.0.0.1;dbname=c_red,root,123',array(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So the error message lead you to look to `new PDO()` but PHP is actually complaining about `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` in the same line.

Same goes for the `catch` block:

```
 catch(\PDOException $e)
 {
     throw new \PDOException ($e->getMessage);
 }
```

Second: You are missing a closing quote on the DSN string, before the username and password.  The constructor should look fully like:

```
// user, password are 2nd, 3rd arguments to constructor!
self::$conn = new \PDO('mysql:hostname=127.0.0.1;dbname=c_red', 'root', '123', array(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
```

... where `'root'` and `'123'` are separate arguments to the constructor, *not* part of the DSN string.

Note about using [the `use` keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) after comments:

You could import PDO into your namespace with

```
use \PDO;
```

which would allow you to utilize `PDO` and its constants without prefixing them with a backslash.  However, you would *also* have to `use \PDOException` because the exception is not within a `PDO` namespace (there is no such namespace). Both exist at the global namespace, so there may not be much to gain by importing them with `use`. My *opinion* and preference would be to continue prefixing them as `\PDO` and `\PDOException`.

Comment: What about putting `use \PDO;` at the top of the file? Is that frowned upon (speaking as someone who is fairly new to namespacing)?

Comment: @JesseKernaghan That's really a matter of opinion. For something at the global namespace (like PDO) I generally don't `use`.  You could, but `PDOException` would also need to be declared with a `use PDOException`.  If PDO had its own namespace, it would be convenient to `use` it, wherein you'd also get access to the exceptions.